# Android - android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm new to the Android\Java world and I'm having some issues. I have an activity with a fragment container and I'm trying to implement a Navigation Drawer, but I'm getting the following errors:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{uk.co.XXXX.EditFactFind}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #80: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #80: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
        at uk.co.XXXX.EditFactFind.onCreate(EditFactFind.java:40)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: uk.co.**XXXX**EditFactFind cannot be cast to android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
        at uk.co.XXXX.NavigationDrawerFragment.getActionBar(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:272)
        at uk.co.XXXX.NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreateView(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:100)
```

My Activity XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="@string/titleEditText"
        android:id="@+id/titleViewText"    />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/titleViewText"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/titleViewText"
        android:id="@+id/titleEditText"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/titleEditText"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/titleViewText"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="@string/dateTextView"
        android:id="@id/dateTextView"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/saveButton"
        android:id="@id/saveButton"
        android:layout_below="@id/titleEditText"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cancelButton"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:id="@id/cancelButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/saveButton"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/saveButton"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_below="@id/cancelButton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next"
            android:id="@+id/nextButton"/>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:name="uk.co.XXXX.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My Activity Java is:

```
package uk.co.XXXX;


import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;


import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class EditFactFind extends FragmentActivity implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    public static final int RESULT_DELETE = -500;
    private boolean isInEditMode = true;
    private boolean isAddingFactFind = true;
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_factfind);

        final Button saveButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
        final Button cancelButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
        final EditText titleEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.titleEditText);
        //final EditText factFindEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.factFindEditText);
        final TextView dateTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
        final Button nextButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);

        //Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected article
        secA_pg1 iniSecFrag = new secA_pg1();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(secA_pg1.ARG_INDEX, 1);
        iniSecFrag.setArguments(args);

        FragmentTransaction initialTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
        initialTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, iniSecFrag);
        initialTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

        //Commit the transaction
        initialTransaction.commit();

        //// TODO: 10/09/2015  
        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

        Serializable extra = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("FactFind");
        if(extra != null)
        {
            FactFind factFind = (FactFind) extra;
            titleEditText.setText(factFind.getTitle());
          //  factFindEditText.setText(factFind.getFactFindTitle());

            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            String date = dateFormat.format(factFind.getDate());

            dateTextView.setText(date);

            isInEditMode = false;
            titleEditText.setEnabled(false);
          //  factFindEditText.setEnabled(false);
            saveButton.setText("Edit");

            isAddingFactFind = false;

        }

        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, new Intent());
                finish();
            }
        });

        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //secA_pg1 secFrag = (secA_pg1) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.Sec_A_pg1_fragment);
                //Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected article
                secA_pg2 newSecFrag = new secA_pg2();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(secA_pg2.ARG_INDEX, 2);
                newSecFrag.setArguments(args);

                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
                // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newSecFrag);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                //Commit the transaction
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });

        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if(isInEditMode)
                {
                    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                    FactFind factFind = new FactFind(titleEditText.getText().toString(),Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                    returnIntent.putExtra("FactFind", factFind);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                    finish();

                }
                else
                {
                    isInEditMode = true;
                    saveButton.setText("Save");
                    titleEditText.setEnabled(true);
                   // factFindEditText.setEnabled(true);
                }

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.are_you_sure_you_want_to_delete_this_fact_find_it_can_t_be_undone_);
        builder.setTitle("Confirm Delete");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();

                setResult(RESULT_DELETE, returnIntent);
                finish();

            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        builder.create().show();
        return true;

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.nav_drawer, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        else {
            //return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }
    }
    //@Override
    public void onSelectedFragChanged(int index) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        secA_pg1 secA_pg1 = (secA_pg1) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.Sec_A_pg1_fragment);

        secA_pg1.setSectionTitle(index);
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        //actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

    }
}
```

Nav drawer XML is:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="uk.co.XXXX.MainActivity">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
         android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
    <!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="uk.co.XXXX.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and Nav Drawer Java is:

```
package XXXX;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Fragment used for managing interactions for and presentation of a navigation drawer.
 * See the <a href="https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#Interaction">
 * design guidelines</a> for a complete explanation of the behaviors implemented here.
 */
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    /**
     * Remember the position of the selected item.
     */
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

    /**
     * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the user manually
     * expands it. This shared preference tracks this.
     */
    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

    /**
     * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
     */
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

    /**
     * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
     */
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerListView;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;

    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
        // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }

        // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of actions in the action bar.
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                new String[]{
                        getString(R.string.title_section1),
                        getString(R.string.title_section2),
                        getString(R.string.title_section3),
                        "Assets",
                        "ID",
                }));
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
        return mDrawerListView;
    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    /**
     * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation drawer interactions.
     *
     * @param fragmentId   The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
     * @param drawerLayout The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
     */
    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
                    // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
        // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar. See also
        // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the action bar.
        if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
            showGlobalContextActionBar();
        }
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_example) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Example action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to show the global app
     * 'context', rather than just what's in the current screen.
     */
    private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }

    private ActionBar getActionBar() {
         return ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getActionBar();

    }

    /**
     * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must implement.
     */
    public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
        /**
         * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
         */
        void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your actual exception is a `ClassCastException`. And it happens in this line `return ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getActionBar();`... Your activity is NOT an AppCompactActivity... So you cannot cast it...

Comment: I see, so that should be ((FragmentActivity) getActivity()).getActionBar(); Thanks, that's sorted that but now given me another problem to figure out ;)